# FastAPI posting parameters with line break

Tags: python, fastapi

I am writing a FastAPI code where from the client side i will be sending parameters say question and answers. The parameters can have line breaks. how can i deal with this.
My sample code is :

```
## FastApi
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI, UploadFile, File

## Request body and post method
from pydantic import BaseModel
class QA(BaseModel):
    Question : str
    Answer: str
app=FastAPI()
@app.post("/score-QA")
def score_QA(qa: QA):
    
    print ("Question .... ", qa.Question)
    print ("ANSWER >> ", qa.Answer)
```

The error which i get is this :

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        93
      ],
      "msg": "Invalid control character at: line 3 column 47 (char 93)",
      "type": "value_error.jsondecode",
      "ctx": {
        "msg": "Invalid control character at",
        "doc": "{\n  \"Question\": \"This is a sample question? \",\n  \"Answer\": \"I want to test multi-line answer.\n This is a sample test.\"\n}",
        "pos": 93,
        "lineno": 3,
        "colno": 47
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Edited...
Can something like this can be done:

```
@app.post("/getInformation")
async def getInformation(info : Request):
    req_info = await request.body()
    return {
        "status" : "SUCCESS",
        "data" : req_info
    }
```

but then when i see the fastapi docs.. i dont see any parameters which can be passed

Comment: Use a proper request serialization on the client. How are you currently generating the post body? Are you doing this yourself instead of kissing something like `json` which can automatically take care of and special chars?!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Let me check it